# What kind of causality would be broken if black hole singularities would be real?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, causality, singularities

In his article "*The Universe as a Whole*" [1](https://books.google.es/books?id=B5fqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=We+therefore+face+a+crisis+in+theoretical+physics.+Either+classical+general+relativity+breaks+down,+or+effectively+negative+energy+densities+can+exist,+or+causality+breaks+down,+or+singularities+exist+in+nature&source=bl&ots=ZMqk3EHV-w&sig=ACfU3U183rVC2Fhs36ZvwukPoIq8pBlw8w&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKrvTPxs_rAhV-DGMBHTOYAGEQ6AEwCXoECBQQAQ#v=onepage&q=We%20therefore%20face%20a%20crisis%20in%20theoretical%20physics.%20Either%20classical%20general%20relativity%20breaks%20down%2C%20or%20effectively%20negative%20energy%20densities%20can%20exist%2C%20or%20causality%20breaks%20down%2C%20or%20singularities%20exist%20in%20nature&f=false), physicist Dennis Sciama said

> We therefore face a crisis in theoretical physics. Either classical general relativity breaks down, or effectively negative energy densities can exist, or causality breaks down, or singularities exist in nature

Igor D Novikov developed his Self-Consistency Principle [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle) to solve some paradoxes that arose from a certain type of causality violation. He said:

> The only type of causality violation that the authors would find unacceptable is that embodied in the science-fiction concept of going backward in time and killing one's younger self ("changing the past")

What kind of causality violation was Sciama talking about? Was it the kind of violation that produces paradoxes such as the 'Grandfather paradox'? Was the kind of causality violation that Novikov talked about when he proposed his Self-Consistency Principle?

Comment: The inside of a Kerr black hole contains closed timelike curves.  a shrinking black hole horizon is  two-way traversible.  So, if you believe in classical general relativity and in Hawking radiation, there is probably a way to construct some specialized experiment that could violate the grandfather paradox.

Comment: *negative energy densities can exist, or causality breaks down, or singularities exist in nature* this quote does not say that any of causality would be broken, if singularities exist.

Comment: @safesphere: a stack of apparent horizons whose area is decreasing is a timelike surface, which in general is two-way transversible.  For reference, see any of the Ashtekar dynamic horizon papers.  Shrinking horizons, after all, violate the area theorem, which  means they violate all of the energy conditions.  Hawking radiation breaks the "standard, nice" classical GR.

Comment: @A.V.S. Sorry, my question lacked some important context. I have put a link to the article (which I have only been able to find it in a free preview of a book). As you can see, he indicates all of these problems at the end of the 4th section which is about black holes.

Comment: @safesphere but if causality is violated and e.g travellers from the future started the universe, wouldn't that be a paradox/logical contradiction (similar to the grandfather paradox)? I mean, how could these travellers create the universe if the universe did not exist yet in the first place?

Comment: @safesphere: a spacetime that contains CTCs is not predictable from a single timelike hypersurface.  the "grandfather paradox" is an easy to understand way to explain this, but the fact is that the predictive power of the physical theory breaks down if you allow CTCs.

Comment: @safesphere: there is no discussion of staticity anywhere in this question, you introduced that for some reason.  CTCs ruin hyperbolicity, full stop.  If you want to talk through whether that counts, technically as a "grandfather paradox", whatever, but the spacetime becomes acausal and unpredictable.  If you continuously parameterize a spacetime without CTCs to one with them, large caustics will grow as the parameter increases.

Comment: Basically, the type of strong causality that you cite "where you have always killed your grandfather" doesn't make any sense in traditional GR frameworks, because you've ruined the predictibility of the spacetime by allowing CTCs -- small perturbations of the spacetime near the CTC can have arbitrarily large effects, because the CTC provides a path to allow influences to propogate non-locally.